# Create non clustered index times out

Tags: sql-server, ssms

While creating a `non-clustered index` on a `table` using `SSMS`, I get this message. I tried changing the `timeout` setting on the `database` thus, but it doesn't help:

```
USE Options ;  
GO  
EXEC sp_configure 'remote query timeout', 0 ;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE ;  
GO
```

The sql server error:

```
===================================

Create failed for Index 'NonClusteredIndex-20200121-151256'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

------------------------------
For help, click: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=15.0.18142.0+((SSMS_Rel).190722-0816)&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Create+Index&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.CreateImpl()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Index.Create()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.IndexExtender.IndexExtenderHelper.Execute(IndexAction action)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.RelationalEngineTasks.IndexTaskFormComponent.PerformTask(ITaskExecutionContext context)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.RelationalEngineTasks.IndexTaskFormComponent.Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.ITask.Perform(ITaskExecutionContext )
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.TaskForms.TaskExecutionManager.ExecuteTaskSequence(ISfcScriptCollector collector)

===================================

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes executionType, Boolean retry)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(StringCollection sqlCommands, ExecutionTypes executionType, Boolean retry)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExecutionManager.ExecuteNonQuery(StringCollection queries, Boolean retry)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.ExecuteNonQuery(StringCollection queries, Boolean includeDbContext, Boolean executeForAlter)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.CreateImplFinish(StringCollection createQuery, ScriptingPreferences sp)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.CreateImpl()

===================================

**Execution Timeout Expired.**  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

------------------------------
For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=-2&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
Server Name: DELLR410
Error Number: -2
Severity: 11
State: 0


------------------------------
Program Location:
```

Comment: Have you tried to do this by SSMS not with a script?

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified, I  used SSMS to create the nc index.

Comment: In SSMS use `script` button to generate a script (in the window for index creation). This script can run infinitely.

Comment: I am guessing you are using the object explorer to do this. Write the statement out and execute it as a sql statement instead. You can also script the change instead of rewriting it.

Comment: The script suggestion seems to be working - no timeout.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When working with large (millions of records) tables it is advised not to use the built-in functionality of SSMS to do this but via a script. Personally I always use a remote session on the server itself when I run these scripts on large tables, to protect the execution of the script as much as I can (SSMS on my laptop might crash or the network connection gets interrupted etc).
[image]